# Is virtualization or dual booting better for the longevity of my hard drive?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows, virtualbox, hard-disk

I've been using Linux Mint (MATE 21.2) via Oracle Virtualbox and I've actually taken to it more than my host system (Windows 11). I would switch to Mint as my host system since all my important files are either on the cloud or on flash devices. However I was also looking into hard drive partitions, and I think that would be a good option to keep Windows on one side and Mint on the other, however I don't want to risk damaging my hard drive. Which option would be better in order to preserve the longevity of my hard drive?

Comment: "all my important files are either on the cloud or on flash devices..." - this is not a really good idea, unless you make regular backups onto reliable, local devices.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**: What you propose won't cause more disk activity, therefore it won't reduce the longevity of the device.  If anything, what you're doing now is worse for longevity, although it should still be fine assuming normal use.

**My reasoning**
Does your system have a spinning hard drive ("rotating rust"), or flash storage of some sort (eg. SSD, NVMe)?  Each has its own set of weaknesses.

- SSD/NVME have a suggested total number of disk writes that's safe; this varies from model to model
- spinning drives are at risk from: total power on hours, head movement activity, elevated temperature.

With your current setup, you have storage activity caused by both Windows on the hardware (with all of its services) and Linux in the VM (with its services and your own activity).  This must be more activity than either alone will cause, at least I can't think of a plausible scenario where it wouldn't be more :-).

Both Windows and Linux:

- use read caching, which keeps in-memory copies of disk blocks after they've been read once
- use write buffering and (likely) write coalescing.  Together, they may result in fewer writes.

One note: I presume you know about partition resizing tools.  Just for insurance, one should always make a temporary backup if there's anything in the existing partition that you don't want to lose.  Even just reinstalling Windows (and all your applications and settings) can be a waste of time vs. restoring from a system backup.

--klode